# Method signature for Jacobian of a least squares function in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, least-squares

Can anyone provide an example of providing a Jacobian to a [least squares function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html#scipy.optimize.leastsq) in `scipy`?

I can't figure out the method signature they want - they say it should be a function, yet it's very hard to figure out what input parameters in what order this function should accept.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's the exponential decay fitting that I got to work with this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

def f(var,xs):
    return var[0]*np.exp(-var[1]*xs)+var[2]

def func(var, xs, ys):
    return f(var,xs) - ys

def dfunc(var,xs,ys):
    v = np.exp(-var[1]*xs)
    return [v,-var[0]*xs*v,np.ones(len(xs))]

xs = np.linspace(0,4,50)
ys = f([2.5,1.3,0.5],xs)
yn = ys + 0.2*np.random.normal(size=len(xs))
fit = leastsq(func,[10,10,10],args=(xs,yn),Dfun=dfunc,col_deriv=1)
```

If I wanted to use `col_deriv=0`, I think that I would have to basically take the transpose of what I return with dfunc. You're quite right though: the documentation on this isn't so great.

Comment: It does work, yet ironically still fails on the example from my previous question :P okay, i probably should pick some other method

Comment: Yes, as tillsten said. Basically, it's the difference between fitting for exponential decay and exponential growth. That's a big difference. I think that you'll have to try some other method that uses the second derivative to have a chance of solving when you guess the wrong sign to start. It might need an additional momentum term of something like that too.

Comment: Thanks, Justin. 2 Years later, and still helping people.

Comment: Can anyone explain why fit output changes when solving with and without the dfun jacobian funciton? Even when reducing the tolerances...  Is there a way to get leastsq to output the estimated jacobian?